# Passing Image In POST creates weird data uri

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm, data-uri

A little background, I'm passing a data-uri of an image, one of those

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg

as a POST to a Nginx-HHVM server to be processed in PHP. Btw it works on PHP-FPM and not HHVM.

The POST passed in Javacript as an object is this:

```
{
data : data.uri,
transfer : community_header,
transfer_id 'f6d67f12-9de1-48c0-82e6-afdcfe97a031'
}
```

In PHP I get the data like so:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
if(is_string($data)){
    $data = json_decode($data,true);
}
```

What is interesting is this is the result.

```
Array
(
    [{"data":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZAAAADICAYAAADGFbfiAAAgAElEQVR4Xuy9CbwlV1Uu/tVwhjvf2317TKfTmUMSEggyiIiKiCjDA1FBQMYAwgOZAhgIg8g8qaAs4QiAKwBk0JHWnU5xpyMoTLyBgbRYEHOT3KJMgeYiOziMhaVVmdNks1k5/0wglBeigCkNogj98vxzq10o0AEqZPz9HYiKyfRyaYudhN9nYLtQwtTkKOq2jY2tonKdhCbswWQmAs3Xw/8DWJkFg/A6MDIAAAAASUVORK5CYII] => ","transfer":"community_header","transfer_id":"f6d67f12-9de1-48c0-82e6-afdcfe97a031"}
)
```

Now I've truncated the data-uri for clarity by the array is really messed up and I cannot figure out. Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug, particularly if the result is different than with PHP-FPM. Can you [file a bug on our GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues) with the details, hopefully including an isolated repro case? It looks like you've already narrowed it down a lot, so hopefully getting an isolated repro isn't much work :)